# Best way to find 'quite good' numbers up to 1 million?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, math, perfect-numbers

I am working on an assignment involving 'quite good' numbers. The task describes them as:

"A "quite good" number is an integer whose "badness" – the size of the difference between the sum of its divisors and the number itself – is not greater than a specified value. For example, if the maximum badness is set at 3, there are 12 "quite good" numbers less than 100: 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 16, 18, 20, 28, 32, and 64; Your task is to write a C++ program, quitegood, that determines numbers of a specified maximum badness that are less than a specified value. The limiting value and maximum badness are specified as command-line arguments when the program is executed."

The task asks me to write a program that prints perfect numbers with a specified badness limit up to a million. So, the command line argument of **quitegood 1000000
1** should print **2 4 6 8 16 28 32 64 128 256 496 512 1024 2048 4096 8128 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072
262144 524288**.

I have gotten this to work with the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const int limit = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000000;
    const int badness = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 10;

    for(int number = 2; number < limit; number++) {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int factor = 2; factor < number; factor++){
            if (number % factor == 0) {
                sum += factor;
            }
        }

        if (number >= (sum - badness) && number <= (sum + badness)) {
            cout << number << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only issue is that this code is far too slow finding the 'quite good' numbers up to 1 million. Is there any way of optimising this?

Thank you

Comment: Why are not all primes in the set of values <= 100 with badness 3? A prime is divisible by one and itself, so the badness of every prime should be 1...

Comment: @fabian they are obviously talking about proper divisors, i.e. not including the number itself.

Comment: A number is "quite good" in a similar way to a number being "perfect" (n is perfect if the sum of divisors of n excluding n are equal to n). But without the definition, it's clear from the code which is described as working (but too slow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If f is a factor of n then so is n/f (although when f is the square-root of n, f and n/f are the same factor). So you can make the code a lot faster by counting factors only up to sqrt(number), and then when you find one also include the matching factor number/factor (except for the square-root case).

```
for (int factor = 2; factor * factor <= number; factor++){
    if (number % factor == 0) {
        sum += factor;
        if (factor * factor != number) {
            sum += number / factor;
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs in 1.554s on my machine in the case of `limit` being 1 million, and `badness` 1. I got bored after several minutes waiting for the original code to complete.

To make the code even faster, you can find the prime factorization of the number, and use the [formula for the sum of the divisors based on the prime factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163245/finding-sum-of-factors-of-a-number-using-prime-factorization).

Even without pre-computing the primes, using this method runs in 0.713s on my machine. Here's my code to compute `sum` from `number`:

```
int n = number;
int i = 2;
while (n > 1) {
    if (i * i > n) {
        sum *= (n + 1);
        break;
    }
    int pp = i;
    while (n % i == 0) {
        pp *= i;
        n /= i;
    }
    sum *= (pp - 1) / (i - 1);
    i += 1;
}
sum -= number;
```

It finds all prime powers that divide `number`, and for each `p^m` multiplies `sum` by (p^(m+1) - 1) / (p - 1). Like the first solution, it stops early, when `i*i > n`, which at that point means `n` is a prime.

It's a lot faster than the first solution in the average case, because although we're still doing trial division, `n` gets smaller as prime factors are found.

If you have precomputed a large enough list of primes (that is, it includes at least one larger than the square root of limit), you can be a little more efficient again in computing `sum`:

```
int n = number;
for (int i = 0; primes[i] * primes[i] <= n; ++i) {
    int pp = primes[i];
    while (n % primes[i] == 0) {
        pp *= primes[i];
        n /= primes[i];
    }
    sum *= (pp - 1) / (primes[i] - 1);
}
if (n > 1) sum *= (n + 1);
sum -= number;
```

The code with this way of computing `sum` runs in 0.189s on my machine.